# Preventing a webview attempt opening an app

Tags: android, android-intent, android-webview

I am attempting to create a webview Android app that loads [this 3rd party website (www.daraz.lk)](https://www.daraz.lk/). The website loads succesfully, but then after few seconds, the webview jumps to this screen, which is an attempt to open their native Android app.

[image: Webpage not available]

When I visit the website on Chrome mobile browser, there is no such redirection. How can I suppress this redirection attempt?

Comment: Create a class which `extends WebViewClient` and override `boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, String url)` method. And, set `yourWebView.setWebViewClient(new YourExtendedWebViewClient());` in your code. Whenever any URL redirection happens in the page that you have loaded, this method gets called and you can have to control over redirection. Follow docs for more information.

Comment: wow! I'm gonna try this out tomorrow, thank you @UmaSankar